# EclEmma 2.3.2 support for Eclipse Mars 4.5

Tags: eclipse, junit, eclemma

Has anyone had success getting EclEmma 2.3.2 installed in Eclipse Mars 4.5?  I used the Eclipse Marketplace to install EclEmma, however, upon Eclipse restarting the EclEmma Coverage was not available via Run launch mode, toolbar, nor the Run menu as stated on the [EclEmma installation](http://eclemma.org/userdoc/launching.html) page.

Comment: I'm on Mars.1 with EclEmma 2.3.2. Works great. Sorry for your troubles. :-(

Answer (score 0):

I've sometimes had problems with the marketplace.  In those cases, I use the update site.

Follow directions for the [Option 2. Update Site](http://eclemma.org/installation.html)

> 1. From your Eclipse menu select Help → Install New Software...
> 2. In the Install dialog enter http://update.eclemma.org/ at the Work with field.
> 3. Check the latest EclEmma version and press Next
> 4. Follow the steps in the installation wizard.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Tried the update site as well as manual installation without success.

Comment: There were no errors during installation.  I simply went back to Eclipse 4.4 Luna and EclEmma is working fine.  Our team was also seeing some inconsistency with the Git plugin for Mars as well.  So we decided to use Luna for a few more months before we upgrade to Mars.